# Upgrading Magento vs Applying Security Patches

Tags: upgrade, patches, ce-1.9.2.0

We're on v1.9.1.1 of Magento which was released on May 1, 2015.  We need to install the security patches SUPEE-5994 & SUPEE-6285 which were released after this date.  But I see that v1.9.2 is out and it includes both these patches.

- Am I better of just upgrading to v1.9.2 or should I just apply the patches?
- What is the best way of doing this? Do I just merge v1.9.2 into my root directory and open the site in my browser?

Comment: I would patch and wait until this bug http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/870 has been fixed. 1.9.2 may well incorrectly display cached static blocks in your shop after upgrading.

Comment: @paj good point, didn't consider that! But upgraded already :(

Comment: This is a good workaround that will fix the bug until Magento release an update. https://github.com/progammer-rkt/Rkt_SbCache

Answer (score 2):

You are better to upgrade to 1.9.2 especially since the increment is so small. The process I would do is first backup your site and your database. Put up your maintenance flag then you can use rsync to transfer the new 1.9.2 files into your site. Make sure you whitelist your own IP so you can access the site yourself. Clear your cache and turn off indexing before you start.

Once your maintenance flag is up you can copy the files into your folder and browse to your site. Clear your cache again and login to Admin you will see your new version.

Comment: thanks it was so easy to upgrade I just downloaded and merged the 1.9.2 files with our staging site and it just upgraded as soon as I logged in.  I guess Magento can see which modules have been upgraded by their version number and it runs the upgrade scripts on the database. It would be nice to get a success message though on completing an upgrade!